# Pick a random variable then have it become unavailable to be chosen again in Python?

Tags: python

I am making a small game for a chemistry project where the console prints a randomly chosen question from 20 of them stored in variables, the user answers the question,  and then that question becomes unavailable to be randomly picked again.  How would I go about doing the part where it randomly picks a variable then doesn't allow it to be chosen again?

Comment: Are they stored in a list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a list of questions called `lst`, you could simply do:

```
import random
random.shuffle(lst)
```

This shuffles the list into a random order. Then each time you want a question, you remove the last element from the list:

```
question = lst.pop()
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
import random

your_questions = ['question %d' % i for i in range(20)]
random.shuffle(your_questions)

for question in your_questions:
    print question
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for random sample without replacement. You can

```
import random

print random.SystemRandom().sample(L,20)
```

Where `L` is a list of your questions, and `20` is the length of the random (without-replacement) list to be returned. So here, your list `L` would be a list of 20 strings that represent your questions.

Note: This returns a random list.

Answer (score 0):

Although @David Robinson's answer is the best, you can also do something like:

import random
lst = [...] # contains questions

Now every time you need a question:

```
choiceIndex = random.randint(0, len(lst)-1) # you want to do -1 since randint
choice = lst[choiceIndex]                   # is inclusive and indices start at 0
del lst[choiceIndex]
```